# Personal dashboard with API integrations to Asana, Slack, Google Calendar, etc

Tags: saas, dashboard

I'm in the midst of launching a small startup with another person. We would like to have a "Dashboard" start page in our browsers.

There are a lot of Dashboard software services out there, and most of them seem to focus on CRM and Marketing metrics. We are not in a business where that sort of graphed data is relevant.

Instead, I would like to have a place that gathers things of more tacit nature:

- Todo-lists, preferably with Asana integration
- Feed/summary from Slack
- Calendar, preferably with Google Calendar integration
- Relevant news articles, e.g. saves from Pocket or Flipboard
- Plus the usual stuff, like Facebook/Twitter/Instagram/Pinterest etc.

Is there such a Dashboard out there?

Again, the focus is not on "graphs and metrics", but rather tying up our many disparate apps and SaaS into one place for quick oversight.

Obviously, the deeper it integrates with services, the better.

Pricing, etc, is not a concern at this point. I'm more interested in gaining awareness of potential services or open-source solutions out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [Klipfolio](https://www.klipfolio.com/integrations)? It enables you to create dashboards using integration with all the services you mention above (apart from Pocket/Flipboard, but you can create a Pocket RSS feed).

Answer (score 1):

[Smashing](https://github.com/Smashing/smashing) is an open-source alternative that’s more aimed towards displaying on monitors/TV screens, and doesn't offer so much in the way of interactivity. But I've begun experimenting in how to modify it and write API integrations to allow it to control more things.